# Renaming vectors in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which, summarised, looks like this:

```
                            CEMETERY    SEX CONTEXT RaHD.L RaHD.R
1           Medieval-St. Mary Graces FEMALE    7172   21.2   21.6
2           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE    6225   23.9   25.2
3           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE    9987   23.9   23.5
4           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   11475   22.4   22.3
5           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   12356   25.8   25.4
6           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   12525   22.4   22.3
7           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   12785   22.9   22.6
8           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   13840   22.5   22.9
9             Medieval-Spital Square FEMALE     383   21.5   22.0
10            Medieval-Spital Square   MALE      31   23.3   22.0
17  Post-Medieval-Chelsea Old Church FEMALE      19   20.0   20.6
18  Post-Medieval-Chelsea Old Church FEMALE      31   19.5   20.0
19  Post-Medieval-Chelsea Old Church FEMALE      39   19.6   19.2
41 Post-Medieval-St. Thomas Hospital FEMALE      60   21.8   22.6
43 Post-Medieval-St. Thomas Hospital   MALE      83   22.4   23.0
```

I want to change the vectors in the CEMETERY column to simply 'Medieval' and 'Post-Medieval', instead of having the entire cemetery name, or alternatively create a new column stating 'Medieval' or 'Post-medieval'.

Comment: Read about ifelse.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` to capture the substring upto "Medieval" and then in the replacement use the backreference (`\\1`) for the captured substring

```
df1$CEMETERY <- sub("(.*(M|m)edieval).*", "\\1", df1$CEMETERY)
df1$CEMETERY
#[1] "Medieval"      "Medieval"      "Medieval"      "Medieval"     
#[5] "Medieval"      "Medieval"      "Medieval"      "Medieval"     
#[9] "Medieval"      "Medieval"      "Post-Medieval" "Post-Medieval"
#[13] "Post-Medieval" "Post-Medieval" "Post-Medieval"
```

Comment: what about the rows that contain post-medieval data?

Comment: @AislingMurray  I modified the code.  It would pick up both "Medieval' and "medieval"

Comment: is there a need of the `.*` prior to the word `Medieval` what is the purpose? is it wrong not to include the two?

Comment: @Onyambu The OP wants to select either Medieval or Post-Medieval.  The `.*` represents characters up to.  From the example, it seems like the string either starts wtih "Medieval" or "Post-Medieval"

Comment: @Onyambu  That also works.  I just made it explicit.  IN your version, the match starts from "Medieval".  So all other characters up to that are kept intact and not touched

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 0):

In case the information on the location should be kept, there is an alternative approach which splits the `CEMETERY` column at the first hyphen after "Medieval" (which includes splitting after "Post-Medieval") and assigns the two parts to two columns `PERIOD` and `CEMETERY`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, c("PERIOD", "CEMETERY") := tstrsplit(CEMETERY, "(?<=Medieval)-", perl = TRUE)][]
```

> ```
>                CEMETERY    SEX CONTEXT RaHD.L RaHD.R        PERIOD
>  1:     St. Mary Graces FEMALE    7172   21.2   21.6      Medieval
>  2:     St. Mary Graces   MALE    6225   23.9   25.2      Medieval
>  3:     St. Mary Graces   MALE    9987   23.9   23.5      Medieval
>  4:     St. Mary Graces   MALE   11475   22.4   22.3      Medieval
>  5:     St. Mary Graces   MALE   12356   25.8   25.4      Medieval
>  6:     St. Mary Graces   MALE   12525   22.4   22.3      Medieval
>  7:     St. Mary Graces   MALE   12785   22.9   22.6      Medieval
>  8:     St. Mary Graces   MALE   13840   22.5   22.9      Medieval
>  9:       Spital Square FEMALE     383   21.5   22.0      Medieval
> 10:       Spital Square   MALE      31   23.3   22.0      Medieval
> 11:  Chelsea Old Church FEMALE      19   20.0   20.6 Post-Medieval
> 12:  Chelsea Old Church FEMALE      31   19.5   20.0 Post-Medieval
> 13:  Chelsea Old Church FEMALE      39   19.6   19.2 Post-Medieval
> 14: St. Thomas Hospital FEMALE      60   21.8   22.6 Post-Medieval
> 15: St. Thomas Hospital   MALE      83   22.4   23.0 Post-Medieval
> ```

The feature used in the regular expression to identify the correct hyphen to split on is called *positive look-behind*.

#### Data

```
DF <- readr::read_table(
  "                            CEMETERY    SEX CONTEXT RaHD.L RaHD.R
1           Medieval-St. Mary Graces FEMALE    7172   21.2   21.6
2           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE    6225   23.9   25.2
3           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE    9987   23.9   23.5
4           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   11475   22.4   22.3
5           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   12356   25.8   25.4
6           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   12525   22.4   22.3
7           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   12785   22.9   22.6
8           Medieval-St. Mary Graces   MALE   13840   22.5   22.9
9             Medieval-Spital Square FEMALE     383   21.5   22.0
10            Medieval-Spital Square   MALE      31   23.3   22.0
17  Post-Medieval-Chelsea Old Church FEMALE      19   20.0   20.6
18  Post-Medieval-Chelsea Old Church FEMALE      31   19.5   20.0
19  Post-Medieval-Chelsea Old Church FEMALE      39   19.6   19.2
41 Post-Medieval-St. Thomas Hospital FEMALE      60   21.8   22.6
43 Post-Medieval-St. Thomas Hospital   MALE      83   22.4   23.0"
)[, -1]
```